# Tooltip for BarChart

Tags: legending, charts, tooltip

I'm not looking for something super fancy, but just getting BarChart to show X value and Y value seems to be challenging to get. Here's a toy example.

data = {{"Data 1", -10.}, {"Data 2", 3.}, {"Data 3", -2.0}, {
"Data 4", 4.0}}.

BarChart[Tooltip[data]] gives this:

[image: BarChart]

How do I modify Tootip to show {Data 2, 3.0} instead of just 3.0?

Thanks for you help!

gani-

Comment: Also, how do I add a line across y=0?

Answer (score 8):

```
BarChart[Tooltip[#2, {##}] & @@@ data, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

You can also use

```
BarChart[Tooltip[Last @ #, #] & /@ data, Axes -> True]
```

> same picture

Alternatively, you can set the option value for the option `ChartLabels` to `Placed[data, Tooltip]`:

```
BarChart[data[[All, 2]], Axes -> True, ChartLabels -> Placed[data, Tooltip]]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thank you! That is an elegant solution..

Comment: @Gani, you're welcome. And welcome to mma.se.